# Conversion of raw data to table in an excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert my data into table format in excel using vba
The code execution has to be done from different sheet by invoking the source file
And the range has to be dynamic

Here is the code that I have tried

```
    Sub converttbl()

    Dim OpenWb As Workbook
    Set OpenWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\data.xlsb")
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = OpenWb.Worksheets("Data")
      Set wsData = ActiveSheet

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)), , xlYes).Name _
    = "Table1"

MsgBox "Execution completed"


End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: The above code is not working :( It is giving a run time error 1004

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the support...
The below code will work to convert a dynamic range of data to a table

```
Sub converttbl()

    Dim OpenWb As Workbook
    Set OpenWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\data.xlsb")
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = OpenWb.Worksheets("Data")
OpenWb.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = _
    "MyTable"
MsgBox "Execution completed"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the table you need to have the entire range of data as an input, instead of just the upper left cell (A1). Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)), , xlYes).Name _
    = "Table1"
```

Comment: Still it is throwing the same error.. I even tried replacing active sheets with wsData

Comment: I think your problem might lie here:    
    OpenWb.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Select    
    You do not need the Select statement, just delete it.

Also, these two lines make no sense:
Set wsData = OpenWb.Worksheets("Data").  
Set wsData = ActiveSheet.  
You should the one that you don't need.

Comment: After that.. I am getting an error "The worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table."

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code you're using now, otherwise I'm not sure I understand what's happening.

Comment: Hi.. I believe I have provided the required information in the question...
And also provided the solution as my answer....
Can some one up vote the question please

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
Public Function fxOpenCreateTable(ByVal pBook As String, ByVal pSheet As String, ByVal pTable As String) As Boolean
        With Workbooks.Open(pBook)
            .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
            .Sheets(1).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = pTable
        End With
        fxCreateTable = True
    End Function
```